# mysql frm file has been corrupted

Tags: mysql

I was running an ALTER TABLE on my local dev MySQL (v15.1) which runs on a VM, when my VM crashed; this has resulted in a database corruption where, as far as I can see, a `table.frm` file has gone to 0 bytes long, whereas the matching `table.idb` file seems to still contain data (I can vaguely see the data if I drop the `idb` file into a notepad).

How can I recover this table / data - or if I can't then is there a way to view the data from the idb file and then try to rebuild it manually (it only contains about 100 [very important] records).

Annoyingly, I can't seem to even drop the table and build a fixed replacement; (a) I can `DROP TABLE`, but `CREATE TABLE` says `"#1813 - Tablespace for table 'mydb.table' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT."` - and (b) trying to remove the .frm and .ibd files and trying to do a `CREATE TABLE` still gives me a `'#1050 Table ... already exists'` message.

Comment: Try something like this from command line using MySQL.... `mysql -u root -p<MyPassword> -e "repair table table.frm"`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/repair-table.html

Comment: thanks V - but I get "Table 'table.frm' doesn't exist" / "Operation failed"

Comment: Try `mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases` then instead and see what happens: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

Comment: .. thanks again V, but this time - it highlighted the correct [corrupt] table, and said "Repairing tables", followed by the database name and then "Error: Incorrect information in file: '.....frm'" and "error: Corrupt". This doesn't seemed to have repaired the table still. :-(

Comment: The `table.frm` file is trashed. Try moving the `table.frm` and `table.idb` to somewhere else. In the context of MySQL, if you do that, MySQL can’t see/us the file and you can then recreate the table structure. And once that is done there will be a new `table.frm` file. Stop MySQL and move the `table.idb` back into place and start the MySQL server again. The goal here is to recreate a clean `table.frm` which mainly contains the table structure info while `table.idb` contains the actual data.

Comment: Thanks G, but as you can see from my "Annoyingly" additional comments - I can't get rid of the table for some reason.

Comment: @user1432181 You will want to stop the MySQL service so MySQL is not running on the OS. You will then find the correlated table.frm and table.idp files on the local file system as files. When MySQL is stopped, move (or rename) both those files. Now start MySQL and the files should both regenerate, but data will be missing. So stop MySQL again, delete the newly created table.idp file, and then copy or rename the old one back. Now start MySQL and see if all is back in working order. Do the file moves from the local OS file system folder location.

Comment: Thks V, but after stopping mysql, renaming the mytable.frm and mytable.ibd files, and then restarting mysql - the files do not reappear. (I do notice in the `/var/lib/mysql/centos7-vm.err` log file the messages `220914 11:10:06 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mydb/mytable'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.` and `220914 11:10:06 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"mydb"."mytable"', ignored.` when mysql is restarted). Following this link (Tablespace Does Not Exist) seems to ....

Comment: .... allow me to go back into the db and drop the table (even though it claimed the table does not exist)... but after that when I try to create the table again - is says `ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table ... already exists`

Comment: Try to run one of the repair commands after it states it already exist after you renamed and restarted and see if that fixes it. You'll want to put the idb file back in place and delete/rename the new one it created and then restart mysql again. I'm not sure the specific order here, but try all variations. I would keep all copies of the files and just rename until you work out what order resolves and recreates the table just in case. See the answer here in case it helps: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278644/innodb-could-not-find-a-valid-tablespace-file-for-database-table-mariadb-10

Comment: Thanks V, did try a repair a while back but eventually ran out of time - went for the nuclear option and fully rebuilt the the database (backed up all tables, dropped the database, deleted remaining files, rebuild the database, reloaded the available data and then manually added the corrupted table data back in from an latest backup). I suspect that there is something in mysql that is holding onto the existence of my table outside of the .frm and .ibd files (ibdata1? or ib_logfile0/1?).

Comment: Okay, it's hard to tell without being there and understanding your full configuration. I always set any MySQL instances up I have control with the file-per-table configuration --> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-per-table-tablespaces.html. Anytime a table has become corrupt, I am able to repair that table no problem. You got it fixed so that's the main thing, so having backups served its purpose for you!!